# wget screen output can't be redirected to a log file using shell script

Tags: shell

I have s shell script, the content is as below
I hope the screen output could be redirected to templog, 
the screen output not the html content but is like

```
--2012-10-30 15:53:14--  http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=pig
Resolving www.youtube.com... 173.194.34.5, 173.194.34.6, 173.194.34.7, ...
Connecting to www.youtube.com|173.194.34.5|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: “search_result”

    [ <=>                                   ] 108,503     --.-K/s   in 0.07s   

2012-10-30 15:53:15 (1.40 MB/s) - “search_result” saved [108503]
```

but it can't 
I tried 2>&1|cat > templog
still not OK

you can copy the content and make a wget.sh file and then run it
you will notice that the content can not be redirected to templog,

how to deal with this to achieve my target?
thanks

```
keyword=pig
page_nr=3
wget -O search_result http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${keyword}&page=${page_nr} > templog
```

Comment: `-O` already redirects wget's output to a file, in your case that's `search_result`. Since wget isn't outputting to stdout, there's nothing to redirect to your templog.

Comment: that is the wget html content, I want to redirect the error information, the control information like that I added

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to put quotes around your url. `wget` then is using the *stderr* to print on screen, so you also have to the *stderr* instead of the *stdout* (using `2>` instead of `>`):

```
keyword=pig
page_nr=3
wget -O search_result "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${keyword}&page=${page_nr}" 2> templog
```